# Dynamically build child routes using JSON object

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have hardcoded my child routes like below. But i want to built it using a JSON object i.e. below should be dynamically added and its components should be automatically imported. JSON Object can be stored in a file also. Is there a way to achieve the requirement.

```
  [
    { path: 'step1', component: aComponent },
    { path: 'step2', component: bComponent },
    { path: 'step3', component: cComponent },
    { path: 'step4', component: dComponent },
    { path: 'step5', component: eComponent },
    { path: 'step6', component: fComponent }
  ]
```

End result should be like below.

```
 export const abcRoutes: Routes = [
      {
        path: '',
        component: abcLandingComponent,
        children: [
          { path: 'step1', component: aComponent },
          { path: 'step2', component: bComponent },
          { path: 'step3', component: cComponent },
          { path: 'step4', component: dComponent },
          { path: 'step5', component: eComponent },
          { path: 'step6', component: fComponent }
        ]
      }
```

Comment: If I have understood your question correctly, you wish to have this kind of module in your main.ts file where you define the paths? If so how will you define path:'' ??? It could be something else as well may be like path:'somethingelse'? how will you deal with that scenario? Or do you have some rules setup for paths property.

Comment: Could you export them in the end result format and just import them into the module?

Answer (score 0):

Could you export them as this?

```
import { aComponent } from './aComponent.componet';
import { bComponent } from './bComponent.componet';    
etc...

// or use a barrel file. 

import { aComponent, bComponent, etc.. } from './components';

export const childRoutes = [
  { path: 'step1', component: aComponent },
  { path: 'step2', component: bComponent },
  { path: 'step3', component: cComponent },
  { path: 'step4', component: dComponent },
  { path: 'step5', component: eComponent },
  { path: 'step6', component: fComponent }
];
```

And then just import them as?

```
import { childRoutes } from './routes';

export const abcRoutes: Routes = [
{
  path: '',
  component: abcLandingComponent,
  children: childRoutes
}];
```

Comment: How about component importing?

Comment: You would need to do that in the routes.ts as well. If they are all in the same folder or have a known folder structure, then you can import those as well. You could also use a barrel file, that might make it easier.